# How can I get a notification of a file changing before the write takes place?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to store all versions of all files on the disk. The problem is that I dont want to make a copy of the entire disk. Instead, I would like to be notified that a file is about to change so that I can create a copy it then. This would allow files which dont change to not waste disk space. Is there any way I can implement this?

Comment: It's not clear what the "I" is in your question. Are you writing a file system filter driver? A block device driver? An application? Or what?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: A person, duh

Comment: @Mehrdad I doubt that's what he means. I don't think he wants to be personally notified of each write. If that's what he means, there are answers, but they'd be very different from the ones below. (They would involve using a kernel debugger and breakpoints.)

Comment: Or you can use a volume snapshot.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, I, meaning the program

Comment: `FindFirstChangeNotification`  Right here :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083372/listening-to-file-changes-in-c-c-on-windows

Comment: @Michael the problem with that is that the notification takes place after the write to disk. I.e. I cannot recover the original information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is impossible. Once a page is mapped into memory and dirty, subsequent writes to it are not tracked in any way. (That is, multiple writes may be compressed into a single write without the fact that these writes are to a mapped file ever being looked at.)

If you explain in more detail what your outer problem is, there might be a solution to it. You can do it with a file system filter driver, but there would be a pretty painful performance penalty since you'd have to prohibit or restrict memory mapping of files.

There's also an inherent ambiguity in your question. If I do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++) *(WritableFileMapping)=i;
```

Is that 100 writes? Do you want to be notified 100 times?

Comment: I want to be notified before a write to disk. This allows me to open the file myself to make a copy before the write gets through to disk.

Comment: I think you mean a write to the filesystem, not a write to disk. If you were notified on a write to disk, how would you know which file to copy? This really would be a lot easier if you asked a much more precise question. Are you trying to write an application? A driver? What's your outer problem? (It sounds like you want to write a file system filter driver, which is a major project.)

Comment: The outer project is as I say. The program is a backup program which stores all versions of all files on disk. I.e. when one file changes it stores the previous version and the new version. This program will be always running as a service.

Comment: Then you want a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968). There's some example code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/fs-filter-driver-tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. It can be done but not from a user-mode application, you would need to create a kernel-mode file system driver or filter to intercept IO operations and block until the file is copied.