# Scripts for game actor

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, game-engine, actor

I would like to add some scripting to my models/actors. When a new model gets loaded, or a script is changed, the actor reacts.

For now, I have a base Lua class which has, for example, a Update() function and each model/actor should overload this function. But how to implement it? The main problem is that each model needs a unique name for the class,...

1. I was thinking of a table whose key values are the actorID(unique) and the value would be a class inherited from the baseclass, but it's a bit difficult when the script gets reloaded.

   `Objects[ActorID] = Model(paramater)`

   `Objects[ActorID].Update = function() print("Update: actor 1") end`
2. Maybe it's also possible to create a new lua state for each actor.

I got the inspiration for this, from the Leadwerks engine: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-EuS1EYk8o

If anyone knows a good book for scripting in game engines please tell me

### I think i got it:

Here is some pseudo code:

OnNewActorCreated:

```
//Add actor
Objects[param.ID] = createClass(baseclass)

//Check if this actor has a script to run.
if param.hasScript then

   //Add the new ID to the script
   Scripts[param.filename][param.ID]

   Entity = Objects[param.ID]

   doFile(param.filename)

   Entity = nil

end
```

OnFileChanged:

```
foreach id in Scripts[changedfile] do

    Entity = Objects[id]

    dofile(changedfile)

    Entity = nil

end
```

Example Script:

```
//check if Entity is valid
if not Entity then
   print("[Error] Entity is invalid")
else   
    function Entity:Update() 
        print(self.name)
     end
end
```

Could work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the engine in the youtube video works does not rely on an overloaded Update function. The reason they have base classes is to provide default behavior and a common interface to their objects, but is not related to actually updating anything.

They are using functionality presented by the OS to listen for file updates (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083372/listening-to-file-changes-in-c-c-on-windows) for more info on that) and then simply execute the script in the game's lua_State. Since the scripts only modify the type definitions (tables and metatables), when you reload the script (via simple luaL_dofile or equivalent I presume) the new definitions overwrite the old ones and lua happily chugs along using the updated behavior. If you really squint and look at the code the video shows in the editor, you'll notice they are just defining functions, as opposed to running Update methods.

As a final note - if you create new lua_States for each actor, then you will lose the ability to freely pass things around between them in Lua, and will have to write C++ code to manually pass data between two (or more) lua_States.

Edit: With regards to inheritance from a common base object: modifying its metatable will alter the behavior of all objects, so we need to protect against that. One way would be to surround the entity script with guards against modifying the actual common metatable. Before loading the script we save a reference to the base metatable and replace it with a copy that can be used by the script.

In this way the script does not need to create its own metatable and does not need to know how the rest of the engine will refer to it. Instead it just uses the Entity one. Once the script is done defining it's derived behavior, we can give its copy of Entity a new name (one based on the name of the script file, the name of the world object, etc.) and restore Entity to the original reference.

Aside from the above, we gain the added benefit of not persisting changes through different updates. Every time we want to change the script during runtime, we repeat the process and can be confident that if something was added in a previous update it will not remain after we execute an update that removes it. If we simply let the script overwrite metatables, then we cannot remove functions and members without explicitly setting them to `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, thats really interesting and now some points are clear but I still don't know, why they are able to use the var Entity for all models. It's not local and when they change the Update func for one model, all Update functions are also changed because they share the same name. And exactly that happens when I try that.                                                          (I have do say that I'm not sure if the use Entity for all models)

Comment: I looked into the engine itself a bit and it seems that they're making a distinction between regular scripts and entity scripts, which leads me to believe they're also handled differently. I would assume there's some metatable magic going on behind the scenes. For example, just before loading an entity script you can save a reference to the original Entity (or at least its metatable) and replace it with a copy, load the script, then restore the original Entity. Makes sense if you want script updates to not contain changes introduced in previous ones, that were not overwritten.

Comment: This way the original Entity metatable is not poluted, you can refer to Entity (as opposed to making your own metatables, which would leave a possibility for the user screwing up and making an object that's incompatible with the rest of the engine), and when an update happens, you start with a fresh copy of Entity. Otherwise if you define Entity:foo, then change your mind and remove it, it will remain in the lua_State since nothing overwrote it. (ran out of comment space, so I'll probably update the answer if you're satisfied with the explanation)

Comment: Big thanks for all the effort, you pointed me in the right direction